# DayOFweek add int value in c#

Tags: c#, date, calendar, dayofweek

Is there any way that with a `DayOFweek` object, with for example, value `monday`, that i can add +1 int value, so now the object value equals tuesday? Like for example:

```
DayOfWeek dayofweek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
dayofweek = dayofweek.addDay(1);
```

I've invented this code so you can understand what i mean. Hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a number directly:

```
DayOfWeek dayofweek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
dayofweek = (DayOfWeek)((int)(dayofweek + 1) % 7); //this will be tuesday
```

Edit: adjusted to account for Saturday->Sunday

Comment: Unless dayofweek is Saturday

Comment: If you want to also account for Sat -> Sun then `dayofweek = (DayOfWeek)((int)(dayofweek + 1) % 7);`